# Problem with WireShark (MySQL sniffing)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, wireshark, sniffing

How can I snif MySQL data using WireShark? Also I used «mysqlsniffer» and have no results. There are no any packets from MySQL. I've filtered by «MySQL.isPresent» in WireShark but nothing happened.

MySQL installed on Ubuntu 10.10 from repository.
Here is my.conf: http://pastebin.com/jkJU773E

Also I can telnet to MySQL:

`halo@desktop:~$ telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
?
5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1�otw|(N2iL~Vsam~Sbr9
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
halo@desktop:~$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, on localhost, mysql actually connects over a UNIX socket.  Add `-h 127.0.0.1` to your `mysql` line to force communication over TCP.

Comment: But how to start mysql daemon with -h?

Comment: mysqld should be listening on localhost anyway, so you should only need the -h switch on the client as @BMDan said. You can check if mysqld is listening on all interfaces using `netstat -ntlp | grep 3306`.

Comment: Tried to comment bind-address, nothing changed.

Comment: Does your sniffer--either WireShark (set to `port 3306` instead of `MySQL.isPresent`) or the MySQL-specific one--capture anything when you use telnet to port 3306?  If yes, then your issue is that your mysql client program is using a socket to communicate.  If no, then something else is going on; most likely, that you aren't specifying the correct interface(s) on which to sniif.  Please let us know the outcome of this test.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're sniffing the right interface? If you're connecting locally as in your example you should attach to the loopback interface (`lo`) instead of `eth0` or any other `eth*`.

I don't know MySQL.isPresent, have you tried filtering tcp port 3306? It should be enough, really.

As an alternative, you can capture the traffic using tcpdump on the commandline and then open the dump file with wireshark:

```
tcpdump -nli lo port 3306 -s 0 -w mysql.dump
wireshark mysql.dump
```

Replace lo with eth0, etc. if needed.

Comment: Yes I am using vurtyal «Any Interfaces option» and tried to use all interfaces.

Comment: halo@desktop:~$ sudo tcpdump -nli lo port 3306 -s 0 -w mysql.dump
[sudo] password for halo: 
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
and thats all :(

Comment: Yes, tcpdump should keep running while you do the connection testing; then you quit it using CTRL-C and launch wireshark, should have told you that. But @BMDan may be on the right track anyway, you should make sure you're not connecting via a socket on your tests first.

Comment: I tried to query mysql, all is ok but no anything logged by tcpdump anyway :(